# how to redirect to child route in nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

i want to redirect to child route, if user entered to `localhost:3000/browse`,
he redirect to `localhost:3000/browse/songs/new`.
but i don't know how to do it!

and i don't know what is the best component structure for this example

my routes will be like this:

```
localhost:3000/browse/songs/new
localhost:3000/browse/songs/popular
localhost:3000/browse/songs/top
localhost:3000/browse/songs/podcasts
localhost:3000/browse/songs/playlist
```

and in all of theme, i have a common section, but contents are difrent.

[common section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTtIA.png)

Answer (score 12):

If you only have one location to redirect to, check out Andrew1325's answer. If there are multiple route-to-redirect match-ups, [this thread](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/112) has some ideas.

The way I do it is with "anonymous" middleware, like so:

In /pages/browse/index.js

```js
<script>
export default {
    middleware: [
        function({ redirect }) {
            redirect('/browse/songs/new');
        },
    ],
};
</script>
```

Comment: Add the checks as mentioned in @Miracool's answer to avoid the circular redirection.

Answer (score 6):

To redirect automatically or under certain conditions you need to use **middleware**. This can be setup like this:

```
//browse/index.js
<template>
  //no need for content as redirecting
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'redirect'
}
</script>
```

and your middleware file...

```
//middleware/redirect.js
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  // automatic redirect
  return redirect('/browse/songs/new')
}
```

Read about middleware [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/)

Your pages structure is set up in the **pages** folder and you name folders and pages as you would like your routes to be.

Read about it [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/)

To use a common theme you can use **layouts**. These will have a `<nuxt-child/>` section which will display the individual page content.

You can read about them [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views/#layouts)

All of this is pretty basic nuxt stuff, you should take some time to read the documantation or look at some tutorials listed [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/awesome-nuxt#tutorials).

Answer (score 2):

Big ups to [@parker_codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599694/how-to-redirect-to-child-route-in-nuxt#answer-55601274), there is a little deficiency is his implementation which is **circular redirection** a.k.a forever redirect loop.

To solve this, add some checks in the parent component. This is because `Nuxt Js` calls the middleware of a parent route anytime a child route is visited.

```html
//browse/index.js
<template>
  //no need for content as redirecting
  <NuxtChild />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware({ route, redirect, from }) {
    if(route.path == "/browse" || route.path == "/browse/"){
     return redirect("/browse/songs/new")
    }

  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also nice solution.

```
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  redirect: "/browse/songs/new",
});
</script>
```